# No module named sendgrid in Python script in Heroku scheduler inside Rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduler, sendgrid

I've deployed a Rails application on Heroku. I also have a Python script inside the Rails bin folder. I am now using Heroku scheduler to run the Python script every 10 minutes. I want to test it first. So I run:

```
heroku run python bin/notify.py
```

in my local terminal. Then I got the following error message:

```
Running python bin/notify.py on ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/notify.py", line 6, in <module>
    import sendgrid
ImportError: No module named sendgrid
```

However, I've already had the sendgrid addon on Heroku. I can also use sendgrid in my Rails code without any problem.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If so, did you confirm that sendgrid is installed in that virtualenv? Or that you are using the virtualenv when trying to run the python script?

Comment: I used puma as the webserver for this Rails application. I don't know about virtualenv, so I believe I didn't use it.

Comment: On your server, you validated that sendgrid is actually there?

Comment: I used the free Heroku account. I deployed it from my Mac using command "heroku create" and "git push heroku". I added the sendgrid addon in Heroku using "heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter". Inside my Rails app, there is a "confirm" button that will send a confirmation email via sendgrid. I've checked it works. The Python script does some backend data extraction from an API and checks the database and sends an email notification when requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: Ah. This seems very heroku specific. Unfortunately, I have not used that much heroku. Not much help from me, sorry. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Heroku tech support. They told me I have to install both the ruby and python buildpack and include sendgrid in the requirements.txt in the application root directory.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Issue resolved.

Comment: You've been faster after 6 hours of silence in this question... ;)

Comment: Yeah. I was busy contacting Heroku tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot to install [Python's sendgrid dependency](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/python.html) when building the container. See [declare Python app dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies) for how to install Python dependencies. As you are running both, ruby and Python, you have to install both buildpacks to ensure both dependencies are being loaded.